# Multiple Row and Column via Count Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

So I intend to Query data for a couple of charts in MySQL,
The data for the charts come from the same table, but work for multiple Time ranges. So group by doesn't work.

The Date itself I want in the format

```
Total   Oranges  Mangoes  Bananas  Tomatoes
----------------------------------------------
19       5        6          7        1
24       3        7          2        12
14       3        4          5        2
20       5        7          6        2
```

Now, I can get the Initial row using either

```
SELECT 
sum(CASE WHEN Some_Criteria and (created between '2016-03-28' AND '2016-03-29')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Total , 
sum(CASE WHEN Some_Other_Criteria  and (created between '2016-03-28' AND '2016-03-29')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Oranges
...
from SomeTable.Table1
left join OtherTable ON SomeId = OtherId
```

OR via

```
SELECT
(SELECT count(distinct Field) FROM from SomeTable.Table1 left join OtherTable ON SomeId = OtherId WHERE SomeCriteria and (DateRange)) AS Total
(SELECT count(distinct Field) FROM from SomeTable.Table1 left join OtherTable ON SomeId = OtherId WHERE SomeCriteria and (DateRange)) AS Oranges
...
```

Getting it in the same row would be easy as I just use the above method, but what if I want the data to be in multiple rows but based on the different date ranges?

Comment: Use the first query with a `group by`.

Comment: if `created between ..` is equal for every column you can move to the `where` clause

Answer (score 0):

You'll need those date ranges in a resultset (either a subquery, a temporary table, or a permanent table of some sort). Once you have that you can use your first query with a `JOIN` to your ranges table and then using `GROUP BY` on those ranges.

For example:

```
SELECT
    DR.start_date,
    DR.end_date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Some_Criteria AND (created BETWEEN DR.start_date AND DR.end_date)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Some_Other_Criteria AND (created BETWEEN DR.start_date AND DR.end_date)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Oranges,
...
FROM
    Date_Ranges DR
INNER JOIN SomeTable.Table1 T1 ON
    T1.created >= DR.start_date AND
    T1.created < DR.end_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN OtherTable OT ON OT.SomeId = T1.OtherId
GROUP BY
    DR.start_date,
    DR.end_date
```